# Separar números con Jquery de 3 a 1 2 3

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo una pregunta si tengo un número cualquiera como puedo hacer para separarlo por ejemplo si tengo el 3 que se separe en 1 2 3 en jQuery?
No se me ocurre como poder hacerlo, ¿me pueden ayudar porfa?
Gracias de antemano.

Contexto:
Desde base de datos hay un campo donde se agregan número de habitaciones, imprimo este valor de la siguiente forma

```
 <?php echo $habitaciones ?>
```

Me devuelve el valor 3, lo que deseo es que envez de imprimir el número 3 me imprima los números separados, ejemplo 1, 2, 3

Comment: Hola maicol, por favor lee [ask] no entendí nada de tu pregunta, agrega el código que has intentado utilizar para poder ayudarte de una mejor forma.

Comment: Hola Bender, ya actualice la pregunta

Comment: Todavia no diste suficiente información. Preguntas por JQuery y mostrás una variable en PHP. Supongo que $habitaciones es un arreglo y que es lo que recibe como respuesta una petición HTTP hecha con JQuery, pero tenés que ser un poco más específico para que te podamos ayudar sin tener que estar adivinando.

Answer (score 1):

El uso del ciclo for te podria servir:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
          let numero = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese un numero por favor:"));

        for (let index = numero; index > 0; index--) {
            console.log(index)
            
        }
        });
    </script>
```